# How i can correctly debounce mapDispatchToProps or redux action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, debouncing

I have redux action:

```
export const setSearchText = payload => ({
  type: SEARCH_ACTION,
  payload,
});
```

And following mapDispatchToPros:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onChange: (...args) => setSearchText(...args),
});
```

How i can it debounce?

Comment: [redux-observable](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable) is probably the cleanest option for this.

Comment: @rb612 thank. But i don`t  want load additional library for this small solution

Answer (score 0):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onChange: (...args) =>{
    setTimeout(()=>dispatch(setSearchText(...args)),1000);
  }
});
```

Here the debounce time is set to 1 sec

Hope this code works

Answer (score 0):

```
  onChange: (...args) => debounce(() => dispatch(setSearchText(...args)), 500)
```

This is the debounce function.

```
const debounce = (func, wait) => {
  let timeout;
  return function() {
    const context = this;
    const args = arguments;
    const later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      func.apply(context, args);
    };
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
  };
}
```